# Loading assets in an Android test project

Tags: java, android, testing, assets

I have a file named `cards.csv` in the `assets` directory of an Android test project. I try to open it with

```
InputStream input = this.getContext().getAssets().open("cards.csv");
```

but get

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: cards.csv
>   at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
>   at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315)
>   at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:289)
>   at bbct.android.common.provider.test.BaseballCardSQLHelperTest.setUp(BaseballCardSQLHelperTest.java:56)
>   at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
>   at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
>   at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
>   at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)

Has anyone else experienced a similar problem with Android test projects? What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else stumbling across this question in 2021, use the instrumentation context instead of the usual application context:

```
private val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context
```

Then use that context to get assets or resources:

```
context.assets.open("cards.csv").bufferedReader()
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I haven't done much Android development for a while, but this looks like the right way to solve the problem  currently.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my test case extended `AndroidTestCase` rather than `InstrumentationTestCase`.