# How to load the same JSON file in both an Android app and local unit test?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, android-testing

I have an Android project that displays data from a JSON file. The file is read from the assets directory, following the approach below:

```
src/main/assets/my_file.json

InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open(filename);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
// use StringBuilder to get file contents as String
```

I also have local unit tests which require the same JSON file. In order to avoid the slowness of Instrumentation tests, I am currently loading a duplicate of the file as below:

```
src/main/resources/my_copy.json

File testData = new File(getClass().getResource(filename).getPath());
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(testData);
// read File as before
```

Is there an approach that would allow the JSON file to be stored in one location, whilst running the unit tests on a local JVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Robolectric, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26968924/1127485).

Note that the "assets" directory is an Android concept, it's different from Java resources. That said, you could also move your JSON file from `assets` to `resources`, and use it from both Android and JVM form there like you would in any Java application.

Answer (score 0):

Files in the resource directory can be accessed within Android applications by using [ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)). This returns an InputStream, which can then be used to read the file. This avoids having to duplicate files between resources and the assets directory.

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("my_file.json");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

String line = null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
    }
}
String json = sb.toString();
```