# getting null value from getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, android, kotlin

*Though topic is asked several times. But none of those solutions worked for me.*

My project is as follows

```
../src/main/
    |
    |-- java/media/uqab/api/
    |   |
    |   |-- Api.kt
    |
    |
    |-- assets/
        |
        |-- info_list.json
```

I tried to get the `info_list.json` file from `Api.kt`. But getting a `null` value.

```kotlin
class Api {
    companion object {
        fun getInfoList(): List<Info> {
            //...
            val str: InputStream? = Api::class.java.getResourceAsStream("/assets/info_list.json")
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what happened! It was working even a few days ago.

I also tried [getResourceAsStream returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null). But didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you verify if "assets" folder is in your classpath?

Comment: Update the project once and check.

Comment: This is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26968924/139985.  You can't use the classloader to read assets.  They are not on the classpath. You need to use `Context.getAssets()...` to retrieve them.

Comment: @Stephen Yes. I could do it with Context. But I want to do without context.

Comment: And the two answers I linked to say that you can't.

Comment: @StephenC Previously It was working fine, without any Context. So why do I need it now. I'm not doing any test. So how could it be an answer?

Comment: See the second Q&A.  This is not specific to testing.

Comment: I think I would prefer to trust two answers who say that it can't be done to someone who says it worked before but doesn't work now.  I'm not doubting that you believe that it worked before.  Just that it did work before.   For instance, you might have had an copy of that file in your project's "src/main/res" or "src/main/resources" directory.

Comment: Anyhow, if you do find anything that says that you can load an asset (src/main/asset) via a classloader, people would be interested to know exactly how it is done.

Comment: Though it is not working from inside the library module, in app module is working perfectly. **Why This Is Working In App while Not in Library**